# jQuery Prevent Default - doesn't appear to work in some circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` in various places but it always seems to be a bit of a struggle to get it to work.

I have now hit a wall with the instance:-

```
$("#existing_Flavours").on("keydown", function(event){
    switch(event.which){
        case 9:
            //tab called permit
            break;
        default:
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
    } // end switch
});
```

I want the tab key to work but nothing else.

Been round this endlessly and no matter what I cannot stop normal key strokes from occurring.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); - this won't work in IE8

Comment: try preventing `keypress` instead.

Comment: @socialrel8 It should, jQuery normalizes it.

Comment: @socialrel8 that's a jQuery event, not a native event.

Comment: I'm guessing this works in some browsers and not others. Try adding `return false` at the end of the default.

Comment: Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VbgbR/ tested in chrome and IE7/8/9

Comment: I tried using that recently and it didn't work - kept getting a debug error in IE8

Comment: @JanDvorak only problem with keypress is it doesn't catch special keys such as backspace and arrow keys.

Comment: Are you sure the handler gets run?

Comment: Yes jquery does normalize this I have it working else where without issue. @gargantaun ... ok I am interested in trying to make this return false work. To date I have had no luck with this. Are you saying that I keep the preventDefault stopPopagation AND add return false? If so won't that be trying to the samething twice?

Comment: In jQuery `return false` === both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.

Comment: @KevinB  agreed keypress would not be appropriate here.

Comment: @codepuppy - you have stated in a comment below that `bind` does not work as the element is dynamic, yet you have'nt delegated the event and your `on()` function does exactly what `bind` does? Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @codepuppy Basically, the only thing that could cause your code to not work would be the handler not being called. That can happen if the element is dynamic, or if your selector is wrong.

Comment: @adeneo out of interest would you condense the code to return false? It also worth commenting that some responders are concerned with my switch but here as else where I will probably add further controls.

Comment: To use return false all you have to do is replace both `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` with `return false;`

Comment: It may not be the appropriate place but I would like to know why people edit your posts but don't make any changes. Like above just cross it out and put it back exactly as it was. Is there some advantage to the editor in doing this? I don't understand what it adds to SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element is dynamic you'll need to delegate the event to an element that actually exists when binding the keydown :

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#existing_Flavours", function(event){
   switch(event.which){
      case 9:
           //tab called permit
          break;
      default:
           //event.preventDefault();
           //event.stopPropagation();
           // or just use return false
           return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Ok Brilliant. I knew I had to use the on - But this syntax for the delegate is new to me. I have just had a very quick read round delegate - need to let this sink in - and probably need to revisit the way I have handled some previous code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it has to do with which events actually cause a character to appear. I would try binding to `keydown keyup keypress` to make sure you catch all of them.

Comment: Ah I am using on because #exiting_Flavours is built dynamically. So bind doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

well, first of all, i dont like the switch to much (probably this has nothing to do), try:

```
$("#existing_Flavours").live("keydown", function(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which; 

    if (keyCode != 9) { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Changing the user's coding style does not count as an answer. You are right that in this case a `switch` is probably an overkill.

Comment: Also, live() is deprecated!